# How would I make my code run when I press a button?

Tags: c++

So I'm fairly new to c++ and coding in general, and I tried making a test code that would run when I press a button.
I tried changing for loop to a while loop, but that doesn't help.
Here's what I came up with:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

int main() {

    int i{ 0 };
    bool condition = false;

    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_HOME)) {
        condition = true;
    }

    for (; condition;) {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
        i++;
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_END)) {
            condition = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I thought that the code would work, but the result is this:
[The code runs, but it ends straight away...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LRDF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution, modified to use proper loops.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

int main() {
    while (!GetAsyncKeyState(VK_HOME))
        ;

    for (size_t i {0}; !GetAsyncKeyState(VK_END); ++i)
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a fix, I tried using a goto statement, and it now works.
If you have a more efficient way, please post :D

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

int main() {

    int i{ 0 };
    bool condition = false;

    start:
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_HOME)) {
        condition = true;
    }
    else {
        goto start;
    }

    while(condition) {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
        i++;
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_END)) {
            condition = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use a `while` loop. Try to avoid `goto`.